# Access Google Calendar API after setting up omniauth in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have a rails app that is using the gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'. Everything is working so far. Now I am trying to pull a users calendar after they link their Google account.

I have followed several tutorials, but it seems that I am not able to pull the calendar information. All the tutorials used:

gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.7.0', require: 'google/api_client'

Problem is, I've tried so many times for so long, I am confused as to what the problem could be.

Starting after setting up Omniauth, how do I pull Google Calendar information in my rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work.

I added :google_access_token, :google_refresh_token, and :google_expires_at to my user model. and used:

```
@user.google_access_token  = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["token"]
@user.google_refresh_token = request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["refresh_token"]
@user.google_expires_at    = Time.at request.env["omniauth.auth"]["credentials"]["expires_at"]
@user.save
```

in my omniauth callbacks controller to store it and this to access it.

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:auto_refresh_token => true)
client.authorization.access_token = current_user.google_access_token
client.authorization.refresh_token = current_user.google_refresh_token
client.authorization.client_id = ENV.fetch('google_id')
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV.fetch('google_secret')

if client.authorization.refresh_token && client.authorization.expired?
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
end

service = client.discovered_api('calendar' , 'v3')

response = client.execute(api_method: service.events.list,
        parameters: { 'calendarId' => 'primary' },
          headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })

@items = response.data['items']
```

Comment: Sebhastien, could you take a look at my question (shared as answer)? I hope you don't mind if I share this way. I didn't want to open a new question since my problem is exactly the same like yours was.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking so hard for the correct solution to this using [google-api-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) version `0.9` and I was very grateful to run into [Sophie's blog post with Josh'](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/using-the-google-api-ruby-client-with-google-calendar-api/#comment-2841394544) comment. Here's the quick recap of how I got it to work with their input:

```
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets.rb'

secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.new(
  { "web" => 
    { "access_token" => "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
      "refresh_token" => "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN", 
      "client_id" => "YOUR_CLIENT_ID", 
      "client_secret" => "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
    }
  }
)
cal = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
cal.authorization = secrets.to_authorization
cal.authorization.refresh!

data = cal.list_calendar_lists
```

It might also help to read the [migration to 0.9 manual](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/MIGRATING.md) to see how things have changed with this advent of this new gem version.

Comment: I wonder though, isn't there a way the check if `refresh!` is necessary? If the `access_token` hasn't expired, this would save us an extra trip to Google.

Comment: Yep; that would certainly make sense. I haven't found a way, however and this has worked fine for over a year now, so I'm sticking with this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming user has authorized your application and you have the access token and refresh token stored and the access token has the scope to access the user' calendar.

- **First intialize the client and get a new access_token and specify the service you want to use and its version**

  client=Google::APIClient.new(:auto_refresh_token => true)

  client.authorization.access_token = token

  client.authorization.refresh_token = refresh_token

  client.authorization.client_id = client_id

  client.authorization.client_secret = client_secret

  token = client.authorization.fetch_access_token["access_token"]

  service = client.discovered_api('calendar' , 'v3')
- **use the client object to invoke any api method, here I'm calling 'events.list' to get user events from the calendar**

  `response = client.execute(api_method: service.events.list,
              parameters: { 'calendarId' => 'primary' },
                 headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })`

Comment: I think that might be the core of this issue. I'm not sure I am storing the access token. I am not getting errors, and I am not showing any activity at all in the google developers console. I only see sign in activity. How do I store the access token and refresh token?

Comment: Assuming you are using omniauth-google-oauth2 for authentication all information you need is in the Auth Hash that is returned after successful authentication, more information here https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2#auth-hash .You can follow this tutorial http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/  to check the flow after authentication to store the access token and the refresh token, and for each request you make to api and then you can use the flow above in the answer.

Comment: Yes that is the same tutorial I used to configure oauth. But how do I store the access token and refresh token? It seems like the code you provided above will work, but I am now getting a "Missing Access Token" error.

Answer (score 0):

Could sby tell me, what's the difference between Sebhastien's and my solutions? (My code is not ready yet and don't know yet if I can get the new access_token with my solution.)

1.I just don't get it when and how I can get the new access token and if I need to deal with refresh_token and expires_at attributes.

2.How the `(:auto_refresh_token => true)` and `fetch_access_token!` exactly works?

```
client = Google::APIClient.new
#next 4 lines get the data from app/db
client.authorization.access_token = google_account.token
client.authorization.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_API_KEY']
client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_API_SECRET']
client.authorization.refresh_token = google_account.refresh_token

old_token = client.authorization.access_token
service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
result = client.execute(
  :api_method => service.calendar_list.list,
  :parameters => {},
  :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

new_token = client.authorization.access_token
if old_token != new_token
  Social.update_attribute(token: new_token) #saving new token to db
end

@items = result.data['items']
```