# How to skip examining unauthorized/expired Google access token on the page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-client

Would love to get some help for this specific situation as I have been researching online for a while but couldn't get a clear answer for this:

I have a web app that using API to grab some music concert info that is created in  Ruby on Rail. On this particular page, I am displaying couple concerts' details and I want to add a feature that you can add an concert to your google calendar. I use google calendar api and client id to obtain user's google account accesses. Everything works great until the last part:

As a Google access token will be expired in about an hour, the unauthorized token/code will rise a Google::Apis::AuthorizationError error message and break the page. I did some research that there is a way to refresh token, but so far I have no luck to do so. I am also trying to use a if statement to examine if the token is expired or not, but couldn't target the right asset:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController   
def show

    ## for first time load the page that user doesn't have to do anything with google calendar.         
    if session[:authorization] == nil

    ## for users who granted google account access to load their calendar list.
    else
        client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
        client.update!(session[:authorization]) 
        client.update!(:additional_parameters => {"access_type" => "offline"})
        service = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
        service.authorization = client
        ## the code will start breaking here, so I did a if statement here.
        if client.expires_in > Time.now
           @calendar_list = service.list_calendar_lists
           @test = @calendar_list.items.first.id                   
        else
        ## if the token expired send user to grant the access again.
           client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
           redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s                
        end      
    end                 
end
```

this wouldn't work as the `expires_in` time isn't exactly checking if the token has expired. Any ideas that how I can check the expiry with if statement? or how to refresh the token.

here is also my trigger for user to grant access to their google account:

```
def redirect
     client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
     redirect_to client.authorization_uri.to_s     
end
```

here is the callback method:

```
def callback
    client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_options)
    client.code = params[:code]
    response = client.fetch_access_token!
    session[:authorization] = response
    redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}"
 end
```

private

```
    # google canlendar methods
    def client_options
    {
      client_id: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_id,
      client_secret: Rails.application.secrets.google_client_secret,
      authorization_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      token_credential_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
      scope: Google::Apis::CalendarV3::AUTH_CALENDAR,
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback'
    }
    end
```

Any idea is welcome. This is also my first time posting a question, if there is anything not through, please let me know. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I did some Google authorization long time ago (unfortunately, I do not have the code), but the workflow was like this: ask a user for the permissions, save access token (in a cache, set expire time) and refresh token (for the user, in the database). Then, when making a new request, fetch the token from the cache. If it's not there, then use the refresh token to generate new access token (and again, store it in a cache).

Comment: I believe the approach above is correct.  I am using omniauth for a college WebApp at the moment and thankfully have not had this issue. Could **client.expires_in** be **client.expires_at** in the UserController?   Does the post here help at all?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962350/access-google-calendar-api-after-setting-up-omniauth-in-rails